# Mysql table column Not be null , But column i need null in codeingiter

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

It painful, table column is not null value. My table column 'value' is not null. cause i need it.That's why i set this not null.  When i sync data from other third party some values are being null and it's happen. So if null how to set into column.

here my controller code all ok just need to insert, if null than also insert empty, but table column not need set to be null.

```
$sync_history = array();
$sync_history['total_sync_record'] = $records['count'];
$sync_history['module'] = $records['module'];
$sync_history['sync_time'] =  $records['time'];
$sync_history['sync_by'] = $records['user'];
$sync_history['way'] = $records['way'];
$sync_history['sync_type'] = 'Manual';
$sync_history['operation_type'] = 'Insert';
$sync_history['value'] = $records['value'];

$this->db->insert('sync_data', $sync_history);
```

Here this is problem `$sync_history['value']`. If possible to not change column as null in mysql.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> **Please check with this:**
>
> ```
> ($records['value'] != null || $records['value'] != "") ? $records['value'] : "";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your code

```
if ($records['value'] == null){
     $sync_history['value'] = "";
}
```

With that if $records['value'] is null, you'll insert an empty string to your database

Comment: Without any condition any query or mysql table have to do